# I am getting a echo of my sent message in Facebook Messenger bot

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I am sending a message and then getting the echo of the same message being returned.

```
Webhook received unknown event:  { sender: { id: '1863694633952475' },
  recipient: { id: '1634553643235404' },
  timestamp: 1497369088523,
  message:
   { is_echo: true,
     app_id: 402378593495528,
     mid: 'mid.$cAAafBWtBTQBi02xaC1coicRsq706',
     seq: 165837,
     text: 'Hey Wassup?' } }
Webhook received unknown event:  { sender: { id: '1634553643235404' },
  recipient: { id: '1863694633952475' },
  timestamp: 1497369088953,
  delivery:
   { mids: [ 'mid.$cAAafBWtBTQBi02xaC1coicRsq706' ],
     watermark: 1497369088523,
     seq: 0 } }
Webhook received unknown event:  { sender: { id: '1634553643235404' },
  recipient: { id: '1863694633952475' },
  timestamp: 1497369089474,
  delivery:
   { mids: [ 'mid.$cAAafBWtBTQBi02xaC1coicRsq706' ],
     watermark: 1497369088523,
     seq: 0 } }
```

I am sending the message

> Hey, Wassup!

whenever i get any message. Why is it getting echoed back? Is there any way to stop that echo. And also why am i getting two delivery events on my webhook?

I am using nodejs with express as my server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Check your facebook messenger webhook subscriptions.**

[Facebook Messenger Webhook Events docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference)

Turn off the echoes event, and anything you arent explicitly using. Typically only messages, optins, postbacks, and referral events are used.

The echo event is triggering your code twice.

Comment: Is it why I am getting two delivery events on my webhook?

Comment: Yep, looks like you might be getting message delivery events as well

Comment: Well I needed delivery events for using sender actions.

Comment: The option is in your facebook app admin. Change the events, try again, and report back if you please.

Comment: Hmm, which user sender actions are you using delivery events for?

Comment: @JonChurch I am still getting multiple same events from the webhook, I have removed all of the other triggers and I have only selected the following triggers messages and postbacks, can you please help me I can solve this multiple webhook events issue?